# How to get the calendar to use 12hour display?

Tags: calendar, clock

How can I get Ubuntu's calendar to use the 12 hour display? I've already set the option but it is not taking effect:

[image]

Comment: Pretty weird, here in 16.04 (USA) while I can change the panel to display 12 or 24hr, in the calendar it's always 12hr for both my location and any added. Looking to see if the calendar setting for this is elsewhere, so far haven't found..

Comment: If you log out and back in, are the times then correct? This seems like a bug in the indicator, where it doesn't refresh the event times when this config option changes.